# SQL data displays 1 on barchart

Tags: r, plot, rsqlite

I am four hours into R programming. When I create a barchart from a SQL Script I get all 1's for the bar values. Here are my steps:

```
states =dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT state, COUNT(*) FROM leads GROUP BY state")
```

when I do view(out) it give me this:
[image]

I then try and make a table:

```
state.freq <- table(states$state)
barplot(state.freq)
```

I end up with this, basically all 1's??

[image]

Comment: what is the format of states object,i mean array or json..can you cofirm?

Comment: When I do typeof(states) = "list"
When I do typeof(state.freq) = integer

Comment: states$state will get the response for you as FL LA AK NC and so on
and you are making table of states...
FL LA AK
NC CO HI

Comment: bar chart was plotted for that states and for count

Comment: Change your query as below 
dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT state FROM leads")

Comment: and try now ..it should work as expected because state.freq will take care of that count

Comment: Yes, sir that worked!! Thank you. It's always fun and infuriating to learn a new language. Thanks again.

Comment: yes.. happy my answer helped you :)  ..please mark it as answered and vote if possible :)

Comment: With just comments I am not sure how to mark this answered and to vote for you. Perhaps if you put your comments into a solution then I can mark it and vote

Comment: sorry my bad..posted answer now :) ... now you can vote and mark as answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query as below dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT state FROM leads") and it should work as expected :)